# Meteor iron:router as library in Intellij 14

Tags: intellij-idea, meteor, iron-router

I'm attempting to mark all packages in my Meteor project as JavaScript libraries so I can have features such as auto-completion, etc. in Intellij 14.

Following the instructions [found here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/meteor-support-in-webstorm-9/#comment-115140):

1. I opened up the `package.json` file under `/.meteor`,
2. clicked on the "import packages as libraries" option (yes, iron:router is listed)

However, the `Router` object remains unresolved, even though it worked for the other libraries.  I noticed someone mentioned later:

> Code completion for other Underscore.js functions such as bind, partial, etc and packages like Iron:Router and others are not as complete

**Edit:**
Pressing `alt-enter` with the `Router` object selected, as Matt K suggested, only gives the options of creating a variable named "Router" or renaming the reference, not actually resolving the iron:router library as a dependency.

Does anyone have any suggestions on resolving the iron router library?

Comment: Alt + enter whenever you use something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was as easy as I thought it was with going to `.meteor/packages.json` and clicking on "import packages as libraries".  Not sure what the issue was before but following that same 2-step process whenever the listing changes solves any library recognition issues.